# Logging request with JAX-RS resteasy and ContainerRequestFilter/ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: java, logging, jax-rs, resteasy

I want to log entire request and response body. For logging purposes jax-rs have filters.

```
public class ResponseLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException { 
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream(), "UTF-8")); // It's always empty string
        System.out.println(responseContext.getEntity().toString());  // Here is actual response. It's OK
    }
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException { 
        System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream(), "UTF-8")); // Here is actual response. But this request is empty in main code. 
    }
}
```

In response filter I cant get request body.
In request filter I cat get it but:

- I cant get a link between request body and response body.
- Once wrote request body from stream setting this stream empty and I cant get it in my main code.

I'm using resteasy 3.0.6.

Answer (score 3):

1.To have connection between request and response use:

```
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext paramContainerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext paramContainerResponseContext) throws IOException {
        ...     
    }
```

2. To return the stream to Main code write it back with `setEntityStream`:

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   InputStream in = requestContext.getEntityStream();

   final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
   try {
       ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

       byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();
       ...
       requestContext.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));
   ```

**EDIT**

Adding using @Moritz Becker comment example of link between request body and response body from [ClientLoggingFilter](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/ClientLoggingFilter.java):

> ```
> @Override
>     public void filter(final ClientRequestContext requestContext, final ClientResponseContext responseContext)
>             throws IOException {
>         ...
>         final Object requestId = requestContext.getProperty(LOGGING_ID_PROPERTY);
>         final long id = requestId != null ? (Long) requestId : _id.incrementAndGet();
>
>         final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
>
>         printResponseLine(b, "Client response received", id, responseContext.getStatus());
>         printPrefixedHeaders(b, id, RESPONSE_PREFIX, responseContext.getHeaders());
> ```

Comment: 1. In ContainerResponseFilter requestContext.getEntityStream() it is always  empty.
2. it works, thank you!

Comment: 1. you can execute other operation as   requestContext.getHeaderString("Access-Control-Request-Headers") or requestContext.getProperty("random-token")

Comment: It's OK, but response body is empty and I see no solution to link request body from ContainerRequestFilter to response body in ContainerResponseFilter.

Comment: Also, see `org.glassfish.jersey.logging.ClientLoggingFilter` for how to log request/response.